# Is it possible to get the edit cursor position of any focused editor globally using JavaScript or some plugin?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

There are some `npm` plugins to get the mouse position like **robotjs**, but I could not find anything similar to get the edit cursor position globally.

I am working on a desktop application for windows using electron framework and my requirement is that it should be able to show some menu or window below the edit cursor position. And the cursor could be in any text editor.

Comment: "my requirement is that it should be able to show some menu ..." you need to show us what do you have tried so far.

Comment: @Shashanth my windows application takes audio as input and pastes the transcribed text (speech converted into text) into any editor which has focus. I am able to paste my content into any editor using 'robotjs' npm plugin.So what i need is till the time audio to text conversion is in process i want to show the processing behaviour to user by creating new window at run time.And window will be shown where the edit cursor position lies in the window.So for that i need to have the cursor position but could not find a way to get the cursor position.The focus can be in any window.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`screen.getCursorScreenPoint()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/screen#screengetcursorscreenpoint) function like this:

```
var electron       = require('electron');
var cursorPosition = electron.screen.getCursorScreenPoint();

console.log('x: ' + cursorPosition.x);
console.log('y: ' + cursorPosition.y);
```

And that will  print out the absolute x and y position of the mouse

[Docs for `screen.getCursorScreenPoint()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/screen#screengetcursorscreenpoint)

Comment: thanks, but my requirement is to get the edit cursor position and not the mouse position.

Comment: You mean whenever the cursor turns to select then get the mouse position?

Comment: Whenever any editor is focused, i need to know the edit cursor position in editor.And it can be any editor.Hope you got it.

Comment: ah, I think I got it now but what OS are you trying to do it on?

Comment: its windows desktop application and i am using electron framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the position of the cursor on mouse events using `clientX` and `clientY`

```js
function showCoords(e) {
    const x = e.clientX;
    const y = e.clientY;
    const coords = `X: ${x}, Y: ${y}`
    document.getElementById("coords").innerHTML = coords;
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="showCoords(event)">Click this heading to get coords</h2>

<p id="coords"></p>
```

Comment: i do not have reference of the window. The focused window can be any window. So is it possible to get the cursor position globally?

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem?